# How to scroll list view builder of expansion tile auto scroll to the end of list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am implementing a list view builder with the expandable tile of( 6 Nos).I  just want to display the end of the list view . I am facing problem with when I am click the fifth expandable tile that detail should hide below the screen. I just want to display automatically without scroll. But I cannot able to use the scroll animation because the expandable tile does not have any on click property. I need some help on this ?

Comment: What about using `reverse: true` with the `ListView`? you need to provide the entries in reverse order as well of course.

Comment: I implemented that reverse property(It will display my last expansion tile has first one ).If i click the expansion tile 1 it will automatically scroll up.But if i click the expansion tile last one will hide the data in the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

ExpansionTile has a onExpansionChanged property for a callback. You can set this property to a callback like this to scroll to the bottom:

```
onListExpansionChanged(bool expanded) { //returns if it was expanded (true) or collapsed (false)
    if (expanded) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    }
  }
```

Of course, for that, you need to set the _scrollController:

```
ScrollController _scrollController;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
  }
```

and use it on your ListView:

```
...
ListView(
  controller: _scrollController,
...
```

or

```
...
ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
...
```

Comment: that method is so underrated, thank you so much for this answer